# Partitioning the database for a shared counter

Tags: database, database-design, redis, sharding, horizontal-scaling

During the design of the data store we are looking at a way to partition the entries. The major bottleneck is while partitioning the shared counters. Lets say, we have a n tickets to be offered(Typical train booking, IRCTC e.t.c). How do we partition the data store so that the clients see a live consistency among them(in terms of percentage booked i.e. currentvalue/x).

Aggregation for each read would be too costly to have, any other pointers would be useful.

Also the concurrency is assumed for the write operation (so no oflloading of reads to slaves), and would be fine for the eventually consistency.
But is there as way that the difference in the inconsistency can be minimised across the shards. For e.g the partion of 100 tickets is done like 25, 25, 25, 25 across 4 shards.
At any give point of time the view of the database should be like x% full and how to minimise the inconsistency (naive operations like round robin, hashing e.t.c) among the shards.

Comment: A shared counter, by definition, can't be partitioned. The extreme and easiest solution is to use a separate instance for that counter (how much throughput do you need for that counter?). Other methods, with varying degrees of consistency and accuracy, exist depending on the requirements. You could use, for example, per-partition HyperLogLog and merge them on read very efficiently.

Comment: There could be cases when the single instance might also not be enough, at some point we might need to partition!
Also it might be detrimental for application to give a probabilistic number(in the cases of the reservation of tickets).

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is such that you want to distribute the shared counter to better handle the load of read operations, you could keep the shared counter in its own instance (per suggestion from @ItamarHaber) and stand up N slave instances that replicate from a master instance.  The read operations against that shared counter could then be load-balanced amongst the N slaves.  There's some discussion of rigging master-slave setups via configuration file [here](http://redis.io/topics/replication), and also this documentation about dynamically manipulating slave settings using the [SLAVEOF](http://redis.io/commands/slaveof) command.

The caveat here would be that you have to be okay with directing write operations (`INCR`, `DECR`, etc.) against the master only, perhaps via a queue-based implementation.  This approach would allow distribution of read ops, but I don't know of a way to avoid serializing writes against a common resource unless you're willing to allow for eventual consistency.